# Why would you create this arrow construct in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, arrow-functions

Why would you create this construct in TypeScript?

```
var sayFirstNumber: (firstNumber: number) => void;

sayFirstNumber = function (first: number) {
console.log(first);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That arrow is the TypeScript syntax to define the return type for a function in an interface.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason to do that is if you want to later re-assign `sayFirstNumber` to other implementations. Otherwise you wouldn't need to create a variable like that, you just do:

```
function(first: number):void { 
  console.log(first);
}
```

In your example the arrow construct is just defining the type of `sayFirstNumber`. The `=>` indicates that that `var sayFirstNumber` will expect to be set to some type of function. The left hand side of the `=>` represents the parameters that the function should contain. The right hand side of the `=>` represent the return type that the function should return.